# Some facial beauty standards

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How do the AmE speakers describe the following symbols of beauty and ugliness:
when eg. a girl has very *beautiful* 'big' eyes (not overmuch) how do you call it?
I guess you say:

> **- 1-** She has very beautiful **wide eyes**.

What about the opposite scenario when someone has very big eyes as if their eyes are coming out from their eye socket; perhaps you say:

> **- 2-** She is pop-eyed.
>
> **Note:** in this sense, I need to discover the informal / colloquial term, but about the other sentences, I am looking for the most common way to call such people.

Finally what about someone who has a very wide mouth? I think you should say:

> **- 3-** He has a very wide-mouth

or perhaps:

> **- 4-** He is very wide-mouthed.

PS. for me all the first three sentences work well, but I am not sure if they are the way natives express them. About the #4, I guess it is  little bizarre.

Comment: "wide eye" does have an impression of immaturity. But in literal sense it does mean what you intend. I will use "big beautiful eyes". When I say "big", there are chances of it being over-sized, but the next word "beautiful" brings the impression on right track - regardless of how big the eyes are, they are beautiful. A normal big eye is generally beautiful, but generally an over-sized eye isn't.

Comment: Thanks @Man_From_India; it was helpful, but please let what the natives think of it. ;)

Comment: Exactly. Wait for the natives. Because this is the kind of question that a native speaker can best answer, in my opinion.

Comment: The natives use *beautiful big eyes* or *big beautiful eyes*, but **not** *beautiful wide* eyes to mean *beautiful*. And *big eyes* (without beautiful) refers only to size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) and 3) are OK and sound fine. I won't comment on whether *wide* or *big* is better, as that would depend on the subject and opinion of the writer. Though I think *big* would probably be used more often.

2) I would use [***bug-eyed***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bug-eyed), though this has a negative connotation and could be insulting. In any case, I can't see that any term describing such a condition would be taken positively.

> 4) He is very wide-mouthed.

This seems like you are describing him or his behavior, rather than his mouth. Something like:

> He is very open-mouthed (talkative).

But I doubt you would normally hear a phrase like 4).

Answer (score 3):

1. She has very beautiful **big/large** eyes.

   I would usually use "wide" to refer to a large interocular distance or a look of surprise/fear.  As @Man_From_India suggests, the opposite word order ("She has big beautiful eyes") would be more natural, and emphasizes the beauty aspect more.
2. She has [**bulging**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/graves-disease/multimedia/exophthalmos/img-20007978) eyes.

   "Bulging eyes" could also be used to describe a housefly.
3. He has a very **wide mouth**.

   You would only hyphenate a compound adjective.  Here, "wide" is an adjective, and "mouth" is the noun, and they should be separate words.
4. He is very wide-mouthed.

   Wide-mouthed, like wide-eyed, refers not to the width in the horizontal direction, but to being opened wide.  If you are referring to the side-to-side distance, use expression 3.